# Table repeat region

Tags: php, database, tabular

I am pulling two different variables from the database. A name, and an image path. I want to display this on the page to look like this:

|Image 1|Image 2|Image 3|

|Name 1 |Name 2 |Name 3 |

I currently have this code:

```
<?php do { ?>
<img src="<?php echo $row_UserInfo['image_path'];?>" width="150" height="150"/>
<a href="HorseProfile.php?recordID=<?php echo $row_UserInfo['id']; ?>"style="color:#000000; text-decoration: none; text-align: center;">
<?php echo $row_UserInfo['Name']?></a>
<?php } while ($row_UserInfo = mysql_fetch_assoc($UserInfo)); ?>
```

I tried to add a break after the image so that the name goes right under it, but then when the next image appears, it goes next to the name before. I know this is probably extremely simple, but this has been a problem for me for a while and if someone could open my eyes and show me what I'm doing wrong, that would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you want a table. Is there a reason you can't use a table? Place each image/name in a td. You can align and valign them to get it to look however you like.

Comment: Is the intention to have what appears to be a single row across the page with photo above and the name / link underneath? How many records approx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should enclose your image and link in a `div`, and then `float` the `div`. Here is an example:

```
<?php do { ?>
    <div style="float:left;">
        <div>
            <img src="<?php echo $row_UserInfo['image_path'];?>" width="150" height="150"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <a href="HorseProfile.php?recordID=<?php echo $row_UserInfo['id']; ?>"style="color:#000000; text-decoration: none; text-align: center;">
                <?php echo $row_UserInfo['Name']?>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php } while ($row_UserInfo = mysql_fetch_assoc($UserInfo)); ?>
```

Comment: OH MY GOSH THANK YOU. You saved so much of my programming rage right there. Thank you!!

Comment: I'm glad it helped. If it answered your question, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking on the checkmark next to the answer. Thanks.